# How to ensure that a directive, re-using a shared object, keeps the reference to the original object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to get a directive, with a shared object-instance, to update that instance and then see the changes reflected elsewhere.

Below, I have condensed and simplified my code, to explain the set-up, without having all sorts of irrelevant details to discuss.

Note that in our actual code the `Commitment` is a complex "model" with lots of business logic and additional attributes. And that the `Service` (and less so, the directive) do a lot more (such as handling errors, sending popup notifications, doing some client side validation and so on). So please understand that I'm not making it complex for the sake of making it complex. We really need all these layers, even when I understand that the complexity itself is the root of the problems. 
Also note that the code may not be valid anymore: there may be typos left after removing all the irrelevant parts and condensing the code.

The problem with below code, is that at first both `payments` and both `credit`s are bound just fine. Updating one makes the other one follow. 
However, from then on, doing a second update, angular changes only the one on which the actual update was triggered: it seems that after the first update, both `payments` are no longer pointing to eachother but are decoupled or running in their own scope or some such. This is what I want to solve: to keep them bound together.

I have a directive `commitment`. This gets objects passed in. The commitment is used several times per view, and in that case, it gets the same object passed in. Simplified:

```
<commitment commitment="payment"></commitment>
<commitment commitment="credit"></commitment>
<hr/>
<commitment commitment="payment"></commitment>
<commitment commitment="credit"></commitment>
```

The `payment` and `credit` come from some uiRouter and are instantiated roughly as:

```
 $scope.payment = CommitmentService.buildCommitment();
 $scope.credit  = CommitmentService.buildCommitment();
```

So, now we have two objects, separated and decoupled. a `payment` and a `credit`. But both are used twice: we see the `payment` twice, for example. So two directives are **using the same `payment` object-instance**.

Within the directive, this can be update by some API interaction with a backend. In our code, this goes through a service layer. Again, simplified, first the template:

```
 <a href="" ng-click="toggleState()">it is: {{ commitment.state }}</a>
```

And the directive:

```
  var app = angular.module('app');
  app.directive('commitment', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/commitment.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        commitment: '='
      },
      link: function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.toggleState = function () {
          CommitmentService.update($scope.commitment, { state: "paid" },
            function (commitment) { // success
              $scope.commitment = commitment;
            },
            function (error) { // error
               console.log("error: " + error);
            }
          );
        }; // toggleState()
      } // controller
    };
  }]);
```

And the relevant part from the service:

```
var app = angular.module("app");

app.service('CommitmentService', ['$http', function ($http) {
  this.update = function (commitment, attributes, successMethod, errorMethod) {
    var payload = { commitment: attributes };
    $http.patch(commitment.urls().update, payload).then(
     function (response) { // On Success
       if (successMethod) { successMethod(new Commitment(response.data)); }
      },
      function (response) { // On Error
        if (errorMethod) { errorMethod(response.data); }
      }
    );//patch.then
  }// this.update

  this.buildCommitment() {
    return new Commitment({state: "not paid", amount: 1337 });
  }         
  function Commitment(attributes) {
    this.state = attributes.state;
    this.amount = attributes.amount;
    this.urls = function() {
      { update: attributes.update_link }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: `payment` and `credit` are two separate instances of `Commitment`. If you use the same object Angular should handle the binding for you. If you need to use different objects, you'll need to add the bindings yourself (extend the scope of the `commitment` directive to handle events).

Comment: @vinays84, I know that they are different. Which is why I included them in the example. But note that there are two `payment`s and two `credit`s Both credits and both payments should remain coupled. I'll update the examples to explain that more clearly.